# Ajax: anyone using a RAD tool

Tags: ajax, rad

Does anyone know a good RAD tool for AJAX interface programming?
Is Grails doing the job for you?

Answer (score 3):

If you are comfortable with Java then WaveMaker has a RAD WYSIWYG development tool that uses a mix of the top frameworks to provide a very powerful tool.  It requires no Java experience and creates a standard WAR file for deployment however in the real world experience you will need to do some customization or tweaking with Java.

Hope this helped.